# Flutter: Error when loading scaffold body from a row page seperate file

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, runtime-error, scaffold

I have a home file that contains a bottom app bar, I use it to navigate through 4 other pages by returning them in the Scaffold's body property, I also have an authentification file which also returns either the home page or the sign-in page depending on a Firebase Auth instance.
Meaning it's one page among 4 inside a home page inside an authentification page, when I load it I get this error:

```
Restarted application in 1 057ms.
    ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
    Scaffold.geometryOf() must only be accessed during the paint phase.
    The ScaffoldGeometry is only available during the paint phase, because its value is computed during
    the animation and layout phases prior to painting.
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49  throw_
    packages/flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart 769:10                                                                         .
.
.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/initialization.dart 128:45                 <fn>
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed:
    Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed:
    Error: Assertion failed:
    !_debugDuringDeviceUpdate
    is not true
.
.
.
at loggedHandler (http://localhost:51235/dart_sdk.js:172062:11)
```

I get no errors when I load the Sign-In/Sign-Up pages instead of the home page, sometimes I get this error and sometimes I don't even when I do the exact same navigations, here's the code of the home file:

```
import 'package:application/Pages/barcode.dart';
import 'package:application/Pages/clients.dart';
import 'package:application/Pages/history.dart';
import 'package:application/Pages/menu.dart';
import 'package:application/Pages/more.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}



class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _currentIndex = 4;
  var bnbActions = [
    const Menu(),
    const History(),
    const Barcode(),
    const Clients(),
    const More()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: bnbActions[_currentIndex],
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "scan",
        backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent[400],
        onPressed: () {
          _currentIndex != 2
              ? setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = 2;
                })
              : null;
        },
        child: Icon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.expand,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.grey[50],
        child: IconTheme(
          data: IconThemeData(color: Colors.tealAccent[400]),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _currentIndex != 0
                        ? setState(() {
                            _currentIndex = 0;
                          })
                        : null;
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                      _currentIndex != 0
                          ? Icons.shopping_basket_outlined
                          : Icons.shopping_basket,
                      color: Colors.tealAccent[400]),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                      return 0;
                    }),
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                      return _currentIndex == 0
                          ? Color.fromARGB(20, 29, 233, 182)
                          : Colors.transparent;
                    }),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _currentIndex != 1
                        ? setState(() {
                            _currentIndex = 1;
                          })
                        : null;
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    _currentIndex != 1 ? Icons.receipt_outlined : Icons.receipt,
                    color: Colors.tealAccent[400],
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                      return 0;
                    }),
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                      return _currentIndex == 1
                          ? Color.fromARGB(20, 29, 233, 182)
                          : Colors.transparent;
                    }),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 24.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _currentIndex != 3
                        ? setState(() {
                            _currentIndex = 3;
                          })
                        : null;
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    _currentIndex != 3
                        ? Icons.perm_contact_cal_outlined
                        : Icons.perm_contact_cal,
                    color: Colors.tealAccent[400],
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                      return 0;
                    }),
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                      return _currentIndex == 3
                          ? Color.fromARGB(20, 29, 233, 182)
                          : Colors.transparent;
                    }),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _currentIndex != 4
                        ? setState(() {
                            _currentIndex = 4;
                          })
                        : null;
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    _currentIndex != 4
                        ? Icons.settings_outlined
                        : Icons.settings,
                    color: Colors.tealAccent[400],
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                      return 0;
                    }),
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                      return _currentIndex == 4
                          ? Color.fromARGB(20, 29, 233, 182)
                          : Colors.transparent;
                    }),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Update: The error only shows when I have the mouse cursor inside the app while it's loading.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use PageView().

Comment: I just did, unless I keep the cursor outside of the frame, I still get the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).